# Basic math issue in C using cygwin

Tags: c, math

I am not sure what's going on here, but I have a code sample which is not producing what I expect, here is part in question (just a section):

```
printf("Now enter a Fahrenheit to convert to Centigrade\n");
fflush(stdout);
scanf("%f",&c);
d = (c-32)*(5/9);
printf("%f\n",c);
printf("Your result in Centigrade is %f\n",d);
```

The result when I enter 212 for the input is: Your result in Centigrade is 0.000000

When I make a small change:

```
printf("Now enter a Fahrenheit to convert to Centigrade\n");
fflush(stdout);
scanf("%f",&c);
d = (c-32)*5/9;
printf("%f\n",c);
printf("Your result in Centigrade is %f\n",d);
```

The result now when I enter 212 for the input is: Your result in Centigrade is 100.00000, which is correct.

In math (a+b) * (c/d) is the same as (a+b) * c / d; so what's going on with the zero result with just the extra parentheses?

Comment: It works in Java? Are you sure? https://ideone.com/gmp86S

Comment: What's the type of `c`?

Comment: /*Sorry this does not work in Java, it suffers the same issue as with C.*/
float c = ((a-32)* 5/9); 
//this works

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the behavior of integer division in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602827/what-is-the-behavior-of-integer-division-in-c)

Answer (score 3):

Since both operands are integers, `5/9` results in 0 since integer division is performed. Use `5./9` instead.

Comment: Okay, so in C undefined operands bound by parentheses will default to the higher precedent data type?

Comment: @ChristopherKeveny not exactly. "the usual arithmetic conversions" apply, and then possibly integer promotions. See http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.3.1.8.html or even better -- the c standard itself.

Comment: Not just "by parentheses", but always.

Comment: Thank you everyone.

Comment: Be aware that `5.` is a `double` value; `5.0f` or `5.0F` is a `float` value.  Since `c` is a `float`, there will be conversions from `float` to `double`, and if `d` is a `float` too, then there will be conversions back from `double` to `float`.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you need to be careful about two things.

1. Operator preceedence
2. Automatic type conversion

First, `()` operator has higher preceedence than `*` or `/` operators.

Second , if an expression contains a `float` and and `int`, the `int` will be automatically converted to `float`.

Now in your first case what happens is:

1. `(c - 32)` is calculated, (here 32 is converted to 32.0 and calculation is done). (say this equals `x`)
2. `(5/9)` is calculated. Here both expressions are `int` so nothing is converted to float. And for `int` calculation, `5/9` equals to `0`. Say this equals `y`
3. Your final answer is calculated as `x` * `y`, and since `y` is `0` , your answer is `0.0`.

However in your second case what happens is:

1. `(c - 32)` is calculated, (here 32 is converted to 32.0 and calculation is done).
2. `(c - 32)` * `5` is calculated. Here 5 is converted to `5.0` and calculation is done. (say this equals `x` : `x` is float)
3. `x / 9`  is calculated. Here `9` is converted to `9.0` and calculation is done.

So, you can see in second case, there was not multiplication with a `0` - like in the first case - hence you are getting a non-zero (hopefully correct) answer.

Comment: Thank you sps. The automatic background casting of the fractional quotient to int caught me. (int)(5/9) indeed is zero.

Comment: @ChristopherKeveny: `(5/9)` is zero even without the cast; both operands are integers, so the calculation is done using integer arithmetic.